# Suppose that interest rates are always positive. Then the present value of a cash flow is at most its time value at t=2.

Tags: finance

Suppose that interest rates are always positive. Then the present value of a cash flow is at most its time value at t=2.

Is this true or false?

I think it is false. My reasoning is because the present value of a cash flow at a certain point in time depends on the interest rate and the time value of the cash flow, not just its time value at a specific point in time (like t=2). Therefore, the statement is not accurate.

Can someone tell me if I'm right or wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I agree with your comments. Additionally we can say that the present value is strictly smaller than the time value at t=2: $C_0<C_2$